# Why are my bootstrap rows not laying out properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone tell me why this fiddle isn't working properly? My third and fourth logical rows are on top of one another. It's caused by the `<div class="col-lg-8">`. If I add a col-md-12 like `<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8">` it works as I would expect but as I read the documentation, I don't need that. It also works if I add a `<div class="clear-fix"></div>` before the second `<div class="col-lg-8">`

https://jsfiddle.net/4puugwfb/

Here's the code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="fixed-height">
                double width double width double width double width double width double width double width double width double width double width double width
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="fixed-height">
                single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="fixed-height">
                single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- Problem is this element -->
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="fixed-height">
                double width double width double width double width double width double width double width double width double width double width double width
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="fixed-height">
                single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="fixed-height">
                single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="fixed-height">
                single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="fixed-height">
                single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width single width
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that you don't need col-md-12 in this situation? I have looked at the documentation but they usually put columns in rows that add up to 12 and no more but your columns exceeds that amount. I personally think it would be good practice to add it just so it is explicit how it displays at medium size.

Comment: @Andrew - It's fine to have cols exceeding 12 units. [They simply wrap to a new line](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

Comment: @Jay - what do you mean on top of each other? do you mean the individualy cols stack vertically in seperate rows? Is this only happening at a certain breakpoint/screen width?

Comment: @Skelly - if you look at the fiddle at a resolution where col-md would be targeted the second instance of col-lg-8 behaves in a very unexpected way and is not wrapping as I would expect.

Comment: @Andrew - My understanding is that it's unnecessary to target a full-width element as that it defaults to col-*-12. So that `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">` can be written simply as `<div class="col-lg-8">`

Comment: The comment by Matt Hernandez in this ticket might explain it (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17603). It isn't so much with mobile, so much as whenever the screen falls beneath any breakpoint in v3, if there isn't a .col-* class to handle sizing at that point, the columns break to full width. This is because the styling for the width and float disappear at that breakpoint, and the <div> elements snap to their default browser width, which is 100%. Without it handling the float it won't work.

Comment: Exactly @Jay, or another workaround would be to add 'overflow:auto;' to the inner divs: http://codeply.com/go/Oz6gNLZ0D6